# Use p:dialog to navigate to another page with modal attribute

Tags: jsf, primefaces

So I have a dialog that does the following:
    After entering that page, check if the rendered condition is true, if yes show the dialog. The dialog has a button which link to Page 2. So when hitting Go To Page 2 button, the dialog will disappear and the website redirects to page 2.

```
<h:panelGroup id="panel1" layout="block">
    <h:form id="Form">                
        <p:dialog responsive="true" header="Empty"
                  widgetVar="Empty" id="Empty"
                        rendered="#{Bean.numbers eq null or fn:length(Bean.numbers) eq 0}"
                        visible="#{Bean.numbers eq null or fn:length(Bean.numbers) eq 0}"
                        appendToBody="true">
             <p:commandLink id="goToPage2"
                           process="@this"
                           update="@this,:panel1"
                           value="Go To Page 2"
                           type="button"
                           onstart="PF('statusDialog').show();"
                           oncomplete="PF('statusDialog').hide()"           
                           action="#{Bean.goToPage2 }" />

         </p:dialog>
     </:form>
</:panelGroup>
```

The above code works well. But after I added modal=”true” attribute, and do the same thing, it shows a gray modal block on top of page 2 after rendering. Any ideas why?

Comment: Try to do a redirect in goToPage2 with "?faces-redirect=true"

Answer (score 0):

Primefaces append that gray modal to the body of your page, that's why it doesn't fade when you partially update the page. Try hiding your dialog on the `oncomplete` event of your `p:commandLink`

```
                <p:commandLink id="goToPage2"
                       process="@this"
                       update="@this,:panel1"
                       value="Go To Page 2"
                       type="button"
                       onstart="PF('statusDialog').show();"
                       oncomplete="PF('statusDialog').hide(); PF('Empty').hide()"           
                       action="#{Bean.goToPage2 }" />
```